# How to use this LINQ with multiple "Where"?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have this structure:

```
public class Car
{
   public string Name;
   public IList<Tire> Tires;
}

public class Tire
{
   public string Name;
   public int Size;
}
```

**I want a query to return all Cars that have Tires with size 40.**

I am thinking this way, what am I missing?

```
Cars.Where(x => x.Tires.Where(y => y.Size == 40));
```

This code throws this error: *"Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"*

Comment: Is it actually an acceptable scenario that a car would have multiple tires of different sizes? If not, you might want to consider changing your model to not allow that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want

```
Cars.Where(x => x.Tires.Any(y => y.Size == 40));
```

or

```
Cars.Where(x => x.Tires.All(y => y.Size == 40));
```

Depending on the requirement.

Your version won't work because the outer lambda is actually returning an `IEnumerable<Tire>`, whereas it needs to be a `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

```
Cars.Where(x => x.Tires.Any(y => y.Size == 40));
```